# Is it worthwhile to comment/answer old questions bumped by 'Community'?

Tags: discussion, community-user

I would expect most users to have already found an answer elsewhere, if their question is many months old. If I provide an answer, how am I supposed to know if it was valid, without any feedback from the original user?

Comment: That's the whole reason they're bumped ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you also help other users that have the same problem I ended up into the question by a search.

Answers should be based on experience or facts; so, if you think out of experience that your suggestion could work and it hasn't been listed yet, then you could help someone out there by posting it.

Comment: Ah. Good point. :)